# Send mail inside action django-rest-framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, sendgrid

I am using the Django REST framework and I'm trying to send a mail with sendgrid inside an action.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3U2X.png) is my code:

```py
@action(detail=True, methods=['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'])
    def invite(se1f, request, pk=None):
        workspace = self.get_object()
        if request.method == 'GET':
            users = workspace.users.all()
            serialized = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK, data=serialized.data)
        elif request.method == 'POST':
            id = request.data.get('id', None)
            if id:
                #user = User.objectsoget(id=id)
                user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
                workspace.users.add(user)
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'from@examp1e.com', ['from@examp1e.com'],
                      fail_silently=False)
```

Comment: the mail send function should become before your **`return`** statement

Comment: Please inline your code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call send_mail() before the return statement.

```
@action(detail=True, methods=['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'])
def invite(self, request, pk=None):
    workspace = self.get_object()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        users = workspace.users.all()
        serialized = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK, data=serialized.data)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        id = request.data.get('id', None)
        if id:
            #user = User.objectsoget(id=id)
            user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
            workspace.users.add(user)
            send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'from@examp1e.com', ['from@examp1e.com'],fail_silently=False)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```